# When building an Internet Upload Speed Test, should I store the uploaded data on the server or on a database?

Tags: file-upload, upload, speed-test

So, I've got a few points to ask about:

1. Should I even store the uploaded data from the first place? 
   I'm thinking that if I don't store the data, the upload time is going to be shorter -giving false information-, since uploads usually end up with the server actually processing the data and most probably storing them to a database
2. If I do have to store the data, should I store it in the server, or store to a database? 
   And if I do store on a database, does it make a difference if it's a SQL or NoSQL?
3. When repeating the upload process n number of times to get an average: should I make n files uploaded with one POST request, or n POST requests for the single file?